# Get count and list of cutomers (ID) that have no sales in the last 2 months

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

So, I've 2 tables as under

SALES table:

```
+----+------------+
| ID | SALE_DATE  |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 09-21-2021 |
|  2 | 09-21-2021 |
|  3 | 09-21-2021 |
|  2 | 09-21-2021 |
|  3 | 09-21-2021 |
|  1 | 09-21-2021 |
|  5 | 07-22-2021 |
|  6 | 09-21-2021 |
|  9 | 09-21-2021 |
|  7 | 08-21-2021 |
|  8 | 05-21-2021 |
+----+------------+
```

CUSTOMER Table

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
+----+
```

I want to create 2 measures:

1st would be the count of customers that have no sales in the last 2 months, so in this case it would be 2 (8 and 10)

and second measure would give the list of all those customer ID's (8 and 10)

Right now I use this measure to get the list of all ID's that have no sales in last 2 months

```
show_hide = 

VAR current_name = MIN(SALES[ID])


VAR chk_not_in = 
IF(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            ALL(SALES),
             SALES[ID]= current_name && SALES[SALE_DATE])>  DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())-2, DAY(NOW()))
        )
    )= 0,
    0,
    1
)

VAR chk_in = 
IF(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            ALL(CUSTOMER),
            CUSTOMER[ID] = current_name
        )
    ) = 0,
    0,
    1
)


RETURN IF(chk_in = 1 && chk_not_in = 1, 1, 0)
```

So every ID with a show_hide of "0" would be the ones that dont have any sales in the last 2 months
I was wondering if there's an easy way to do it and also, I'm not sure how to get the count of all those ID's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off - I assume your test data was meant to be 2020 instead of 2021 and the ID in the SALES table is a CUSTOMER ID.

I would address this as a measure and a calculated column.

The measure would calculate the customers that have not sold in the past two months. From your data I think you are missing (4) who has not sold anything - bringing the total customers to three (4, 8, 10).

```
CustomersWithNoSalesIn2Months = 

// Work out what date was 2 months ago
VAR twoMonthsAgo = DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())-2, DAY(NOW()))

// Count the total distinct customers in the customer table
VAR totalCustomers = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Customer[ID]))

// Count how many distinct customers did have sales in the past 2 months
VAR customersWithSalesInTheLast2Months = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sales[ID]), Sales[SALE_DATE] > twoMonthsAgo)

// Subtract the customers who did have sales from the total to get the number of customers that did not have sales
RETURN totalCustomers - customersWithSalesInTheLast2Months
```

The calculated column would be places on the CUSTOMER table and would count how many sales customers had made in the last 2 months.

```
SalesMadeInTheLast2Months = 
VAR MostRecentSale = CALCULATE(MAX(Sales[SALE_DATE]), FILTER(Sales, Customer[ID] = Sales[ID]))
VAR TwoMonthsAgo = DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())-2, DAY(NOW()))
RETURN CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Sales), FILTER(Sales, Sales[SALE_DATE] > TwoMonthsAgo), FILTER(Sales, Sales[ID] = Customer[ID]))
```

Now you can filter on the Customers table for `BLANK` sales or use the counts in any other calculation you need. For example, customers 1,2 & 3 have made the most sales in the past 2 months.

[image]

Comment: this works perfectly good, but there's a limitation in my data, there are a couple of ID's in the SALES table that aren't present in the CUSTOMER table
So, while I process this step
VAR customersWithSalesInTheLast2Months = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sales[ID]), Sales[SALE_DATE] > twoMonthsAgo)

It records those ID's as well, whereas I just want to work with those ID's that had Sales[SALE_DATE] > twoMonthsAgo and are also present in the CUSTOMER table

I wish to disregard the mismatching ID,for instance if there's an ID 12 in SALES, I would want to disregard it as its not in the CUSTOMER tbl

Comment: If you build the calculated column, then your measure can actually be far simpler - CustomersWithNoSalesInLast2Months = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Customer), FILTER(Customer, ISBLANK(Customer[SalesMadeInTheLast2Months])))